# Convert DateTime field to Just Date in Label Expression

Tags: arcgis-desktop, python, labeling, datetime

I have a DateTime field (ex: CreatedDate) and would like to only show the date with the label.  How would I setup the label expression to do this using python?

Answer (score 1):

It is funny that  python interpreter (field calculator) treats Arcgis datetime fields as unicode texts. to extract date from this string, we should convert it to datetime and then extract the date and then convert to string!

Standalone code (assuming you have a datetime formatted like `10/8/2015 3:24:53 AM`):

```
print str(datetime.datetime.strptime(u'10/8/2015 3:24:53 AM',"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p").date())
```

label expression (python parser):

```
def FindLabel ( [DateModified]  ):
  return str(datetime.datetime.strptime([DateModified],"%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S %p").date())
```

Answer (score 0):

The date in a DateTime field is the first 10 characters of the field.

I tried the following in a field called **`last_edited_date`**.

In your label expression, set your parser to Python.

Tick the Advanced box and set your expression to the following:

```
def FindLabel ( [last_edited_date] ):
  return [last_edited_date][:10]
```

And change **`last_edited_date`** to whatever your field is called.  The key here is to use python's string slicing ability.  That is, **`[:10]`** to get the first 10 characters of the field.

[image]

The results look like this:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the negative vote... It's explained and better it works! I use the same solution. But it's a text in findlabel to local format. So yes 10 first caracters return date without time